# Unable to ssh to ubuntu 20.04 on VM from windows 11

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to esteblish connection from windows 11 to ubuntu(vm) on port 22, but it says:

```
    ssh: connect to host 10.0.2.15 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can confirm that ssh is installed and active on ubuntu as well as firewall port 22 is opened. So wtf is going on here any idea? thanks

```
  ssh username@10.0.2.15 -p 22
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [ubuntu.se] or [su]. This question is also relatively common, and googling for the exact error message turns up a few pages discussing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by changing command from

ssh user@10.0.2.15 -p 22

to
ssh -p 2222 user@localhost

In addition to that you will need to make port forwarding from virtual box
where this 2222 port points host(windows port)